# Date issue in ASP.NET Core MVC: when I use type = month in input code not working

Tags: c#, date, asp.net-core-mvc, datefilter

I am creating a monthly sales report. So in date input, I need only month and year, no need for the day. I used type month in input.

This is my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Date">Date</label>
    <input type="month" class="form-control" name="Date" id="Date" />
</div>
```

I need to compare this date with my date in model:

```
public DateTime Entrydate { get; set; }
```

In the controller, for comparing the date in input and entry date

```
private IEnumerable<Sale>GetFilteredData(IEnumerable<Sale>  DateTime? Date)
{
    if (Date != null || Date != default(DateTime))
    {
        result = result.Where(a => a.Entrydate >= Date);
    }
}
```

It worked when I use `type = date` in my input, but when I use month, it is not working. What changes do I need to do to solve this problem?

Comment: HI @muhammed nihal, what do you mean for not working? The input cannot only choose year and month? If so, which browser do you use? Or did you mean when you post the data to backend it displays the day with month and year?

Answer (score 0):

you can use datepicker for select only month and year. datepicker needs some libraries like this

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

after you can write datepicker for entry input

```
  <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'mm/yyyy',
            startView: "months",
            minViewMode: "months",
            language: "tr"
        });
    });        
</script>
```

your input must be like

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class='input-group date datepicker' id='datepicker'>
      <input type='text' class="form-control" asp-for="MyProperty" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

model property

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime MyProperty { get; set; }
```